# Magento table rates and multiple stores?

Tags: magento

I am trying to make my table rates work with my multi store setup. I have 2 stores (not only store views) for the same installation and I want table rates for that.

I tried with the built in table rates and I also tried with http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension.html.

The problem is, this only seems to work for my first store, the second store always tells me that there is no shipping available in the OPC.

I checked the tables `shipping_tablerate` and `shipping_matrixrate` (this one comes from the extension) and both have the website_id column which is `1` (my first store) for me. I tried changing from `1` to `3` (thats the id of my other store), did not help.

This is the content for the extensions file:

```
Land,Region/Staat,Stadt,"Zip/Postal Code From","Zip/Postal Code To","Gewicht From","Gewicht To",Versandkosten,"Delivery Type"
DEU,*,,,,1.1000,2.0000,4.4000,Versand
DEU,*,,,,2.1000,5.0000,6.9900,Versand
DEU,*,,,,0.2000,1.0000,3.9500,Versand
DEU,*,,,,0.0000,0.1000,6.9900,Versand
```

How can I make this work for my second store as well?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you you should be able to set this on different website level, not on store level. Have you contacted extension support?

Comment: @Muk:  I can only import the CSV for the main website (thats Magento standard), its the only place where the CSV upload for the table rates file is shown. Thats what I have done ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to import csv for all websites.
No changes in code.

Comment: I can only import the CSV for the main website, its the only place where the CSV upload for the table rates file is shown. Thats what I have done ...

Comment: Ah yes, thats the solution. I just had to select the second store on the scope drop down. Thanks!